# Embedding scrollable pdf in a rst file

Tags: pdf, restructuredtext, read-the-docs

How to display a scrollable pdf in a rst file. I've already tried `..image::` and `..figure::` but they didn't work and showed only the path to the pdf file like shown below

[image]

Can anyone tell how to embedd a pdf, preferable a scrollable pdf which can be displayed on the rst page rather than a downloadable file using `:download:`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to find a service that will display the PDF such that you can scroll it within an iframe or div. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/291823/2214933

Then use the [`raw` directive](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#raw-data-pass-through) to insert raw HTML.